# Uniqueness of the nth root of an operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ ba a complex Hilbert space and Let $A : D(A)\subset H \to H$ be linear operator such that $${\rm Re} \langle Ax,x\rangle \geq \alpha \|x\|^2\quad \forall x\in D(A).$$
Let now $n$ be an integer such that $n\geq2$ and denote 
$$\Gamma_{r,\delta}:= \{z\in \mathbb{C}| -\pi r < {\rm Arg}(z) \leq \pi r, {\rm Re}(z) \geq \delta\}$$

Assume further that there exist $B :D(B)\subset H\to H$ and $C: D(C)\subset H\to H$ having the following properties:

1. $D(A)\subset D(B)\cap D(C)$
2. There exist $\beta >0$ and $\gamma >0$ such that $\langle Bx,x\rangle \in \Gamma_{\frac{1}{2n},\beta}$ for all $x\in D(B)$ with $\|x\|=1$ and $\langle Cx,x\rangle \in \Gamma_{\frac{1}{2n},\gamma}$ for all $x\in D(C)$ with $\|x\|=1.$
3. Both $B$ and $C$ are invertible with inverses $B^{-1}, C^{-1}\in \mathcal{B}(H).$
4. $C^n = B^n =A$ (in the sense that $D(C^n) =D(B^n) =D(A)$ and $C^n x=B^nx = Ax$ for all  $x \in D(A).$)
5. $B^{-1}C^{-1}= C^{-1}B^{-1}.$

I wonder whether we could prove that $B =C.$

Denote $B_1 = B^{-1}$ and $C_1 = C^{-1}$. The case where $n=2$ is based on the observation that 
$$0= A^{-1}-A^{-1}=  C_1^2 - B_1^2= (C_1+B_1)(C_1-B_1).$$
Indeed, in view of property 5., $C_1, B_1$ commute.
Then using property 2. to conclude that $C_1 = B_1.$

*We might try to prove that if, in general, $D,E$ satisfy assumption 2. with constants $r_1, r_2 < \frac 14$ and $\beta, \gamma >0,$ then $DE$ satisfy the same assumption with constants $r_1+r_2$ and $\gamma \beta \cos((r_1+r_2)\pi)$ *

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Does it hold for a normal operator in a one dimensional space?

Comment: I've just edited assumption 2. Then this hold for your case.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Kato](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kato1.pdf#page=304) has a section 11 "The square root of an m-accretive operator" with a uniqueness theorem. Mentions other fractional powers at the end.

Comment: can you explain better how you conclude for $n=2$ that the two operators are equal?

Comment: Let $w= (C_1-B_1)v$ . Then $(C_1+B_1)w =0$ and in view of assumption 2., we have $0 = Re\langle (C_1+B_1)w, w \rangle  \geq c \|w\|^2 $ for some constant $c>0$ which implies that $w =0$ and $C_1 = B_1.$

Answer (score 0):

It is not true.
Let $H = \mathbb{C}^2$, $A = B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $C = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and let $D(A) = D(B) = D(C) = \left\{ (z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : z_j = x_j + i y_j \text{ such that } x_j \geq \frac{1}{4},\: y_j \geq \frac{1}{4} \right\}$.

$A$, $B$ and $C$ are surjective on their domain. They verify properties 1,3,4,5 for $n=2$.

The property 2 is verified (for example) by $\beta = \gamma = \frac{1}{4}$.

Note that since $A$,$B$ and $C$ are hermitian matrices, so
$$ \langle Ax,x \rangle,\langle Bx,x \rangle,\langle Cx,x \rangle \in \mathbb{R}. $$

Comment: The domain must be a subspace in $H$ ? right ?

Comment: It isn't specified that $D(A),D(B)$ and $D(C)$ must be linear subspaces.

Comment: This is known in the definition of the domain. It is also logic because if not, the linearity of the operator doesn't make sense.